# WebSocket event when pressing keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket

I try to make the client side send a char to the server whenever a specific keyboard is press

Here my code:

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8001');

$(document).keypress(function(e){ // pressing key 
  if(e.keyCode == 119){ // w 
    $("#d-up").css("background-color","#404d4d","opacity","50%"); // hover effect 
      connection.onmessage = function (event) {  //websocket event 
        connection.send("W");
      };
    }
});

$(document).keyup(function(e){  
    $(".button").css("background-color","#1d2323");
  });
```

The server and client is connected but no message was send when i press the w. Appreciate you help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are not sending anything when the key is pressed, you are indicating than if you get a message, then send "W".

You have to call `send` directly.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){ // pressing key 
  if(e.keyCode == 119){ // w 
    $("#d-up").css("background-color","#404d4d","opacity","50%"); // hover effect 
      connection.send("W");
    }
});
```